# How to unnest multiple array columns while preserving the order of the array

Tags: sql, apache-flink, unnest

What is the SQL statement to unnest both columns containing arrays while preserving the array order?

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2,3,4] | [1,2,3,4] |

Expected Result

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT` function like this

```
select * from (
select value as Col1 from test
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace(replace(Col1,'[',''),']',''),',') 
)a
left join (
select value as Col2 from test
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace(replace(Col2,'[',''),']',''),',') 
)b on a.col1 =b.col2
```

[enter link description here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e71c25169279156593dcb6ba99898d90)

Comment: Apologies but col 1 and 2 data type would be ARRAY<INT> not STRING

Comment: convert into string and do it.